# Querying for the exact contents of ManyToManyField in Django

Tags: django, many-to-many

How do I query for an object by checking whether the members of its manyToManyField relation *exactly* matches a given list of objects?

For example, given

```
class Topping(models.Model):
    # ...

class Pizza(models.Model):
    # ...
    toppings = models.ManyToManyField(Topping)
```

I want to get all pizzas that have exactly pepperoni and onions:

```
pep = Topping(name='pepperoni')
pep.save()
onion = Topping(name='onion')
onion.save()
tops = [pep, onion]
p = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__eq=tops)
```

Django provides the `__in` operator, but not `__eq`. How do I do the equivalent?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

How about you filter for all toppings, then ensure that you select the pizza with exactly the number of toppings you specified.

```
from django.db.models import Q
import operator
pizza = (Pizza.objects
    .filter(reduce(operator.or_, [Q(toppings=topping) for topping in tops]))
    .annotate(count=Count('toppings'))
    .filter(count=len(tops))
    )
```

Comment: quite complicated for something seemingly simple. Any other ideas?

Comment: @NP., sorry, I've got no other ideas to ensure you get an exact match. "Find me all pizzas that have toppings XYZ and exactly len(XYZ) toppings"

Comment: Just to comment that I think the use of the operator.or_ is faulty logic.  A pizza object with topics `['Sausage', 'Pepperoni']` would match a query for `['Onion', 'Pepperoni']` since the toppings length is equivalent and the `or` evaluation on the Q objects evaluates to True when matching `topics='Pepperoni'`. You want to filter for each topping in succession to achieve an `and` comparison.

Answer (score -2):

Just chain your filters to get what you want:

```
pep = Topping(name='pepperoni')
pep.save()
onion = Topping(name='onion')
onion.save()
tops = [pep, onion]
p = Pizza.objects.filter(toppings__id=pep.id).filter(toppings__id=onion.id)
```

I haven't come across a better way to do this.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. This still will accept pizzas that have additional toppings